# Python radio buttons not returning correct values, nor is default button being set

Tags: python, radio-button, default

I am writing a Python class that accepts a list of radio button names, produces a dialog box, sets the first radio button as the default, and returns the corresponding index for the radio button selected. Instead, all buttons but the first are selected, and the dialog always returns 0.

Here is the code I am using, and comparing this to other questions here, it should work. This class can create dialogs with both text entries and radio buttons. The 'if' statement checks to see if a list has been sent to create radio buttons from.

```
if self.radio:
       self.radio_val = tk.IntVar()
       for idx, option in enumerate(self.radio):
             radio_button = tk.Radiobutton(dialog, text=option, variable=self.radio_val, value=idx)
             radio_button.pack(anchor="w", padx=x_space, pady=(0, y_space))
```

Comment: "sets the first radio button as the default" (not shown), "all buttons but the first are selected" ... There's an awful lot of conflicting things going on with that first button. Your MRE is too minimal. The "R" means "reproducible", and the only thing this is going to produce is errors that `self.radio` and `dialog` (whatever that is) don't exist. Give me code that I can run which does what you say is happening.